# Origin of hot auras

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, convection

When you wave your hand over a hot object (say food that just came out of the oven), you feel heat even without touching the object.  Is this heat you feel due mainly to radiation, convection, conduction, or something else?

Answer (score -1):

the heat is due to thermal radiation and air free convection.
Thermal radiation is due to the difference between object and hand temperatures.
air free convection: air surrounding the object is heated and therefore will flow up due to density decreasing...

Comment: good answer but try referencing it as well to make it more reliable for the person asking the question

Comment: Some additional detail would be good.